# Basing a GTM trigger on data attributes

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to do some tracking on a specific element of a website, without being able to implement a data layer in the code (development budget is limited at the moment). I'm trying to base my trigger on a CSS selector but it's not working so far.

We have three boxes that are located under the add to cart on https://www.sail.ca/en/browning-high-noon-spotlight-modb-197590. We want to know which of these is being clicked the most.

Here is the code for the 3 boxes :

```
<div class="legal-container">
<div class="sub-container">
<a href="#" data-action="legal-modal" data-component="toggle-modal" data-tab="shipping">
<div class="over-icon"><img src="/skin/frontend/sail/default/nwayo/build/images/common/icon-delivery.svg" alt="Shipping" /></div>
<div class="content">Free shipping on orders over $75</div> </a>
</div>
<div class="sub-container">
<a href="#" data-action="legal-modal" data-component="toggle-modal" data-tab="returns">
<div class="over-icon"><img src="/skin/frontend/sail/default/nwayo/build/images/common/icon-returns.svg" alt="Returns" /></div>
<div class="content">Easy Return</div> </a>
</div>
<div class="sub-container">
<a href="#" data-action="legal-modal" data-component="toggle-modal" data-tab="price_warranty">
<div class="over-icon"><img src="/skin/frontend/sail/default/nwayo/build/images/common/icon-price-warranty.png" alt="Best price" /></div>
<div class="content">Best pricRThe guarantee</div> </a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have created a Data Layer variable using the name gtm.element.dataset.tab

The trigger matches on "Click Element matches CSS selector [data-tab="price_warranty"]

Do you see what I am doing wrong? This is based on a tutorial posted by Lunametrics some time ago (https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2017/07/07/tracking-clicks-custom-data-attributes-google-tag-manager-google-analytics/), but there's visibly something I'm missing.

Thank you so much,
Charles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your click trigger is of the "links only" type. If you have an "click on all elements" then chances are that Click Element is not the element with the attribute, but the image contained within.

This has to do with the way GTM attaches event handlers. GTM does not attach event handlers to elements directly. Instead it attaches event handlers to the document. When an element is clicked the event bubbles up through the DOM until it arrives at the document node. There the target element (Click Element) is inspected if it matches the condition specified in the filter of the click trigger.

If you do a "links only" trigger GTM actually looks at the links only, and since your link has the data attribute that should work for you.

This is a robust way to make sure that events are triggered for dynamically created elements, but it means that it's no always easy to get the desired Click Element.